# AutoResetEvent + Background Worker conjunction with each other

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, autoresetevent

I have a query regarding these two working in conjunction with one another as I am not convinced they go hand in hand.

I have some code which uses the background worker and within DoWork() it performs some logic. This logic simply consumes the TcpClient object and sends data to an external device.

My question is within DoWork() I call AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(). Does this stop the current thread until AutoResetEvent.Set() is called? If for example, AutoResetEvent.Set() is never called will the Background Worker simply halt and not perform any operations?

Not sure whether this is bad design by nature but supporting it unfortunately :(

*EDIT some pseudo code*

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
  //some logic here
  done = System.DateTime.Now.Hour == 10;

  if (!done)
  {
    AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    //Question will the while loop fire again or does it wait for the Set() to be called
    //before continuing?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> within `DoWork()` I call `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`. Does this stop the current thread until `AutoResetEvent.Set()` is called? If for example, `AutoResetEvent.Set()` is never called will the `Background Worker` simply halt and not perform any operations?

The answer to this is yes as cited from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) `WaitHandle.WaitOne Method` will:

> Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.

**EDIT**: for your added code, the while loop will wait for the `Set()`

Comment: Might be a silly question but if for example I had a method which was being called from the background worker and that contained the code for AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() will it act the same?

Comment: Yes it will, as long as the method is within the same thread of the `backgroundworker`.

Comment: Is it possible to determine if Set() was called as my DoWork() method is firing twice on initialize.

Comment: Where did you call `WaitOne()`? If you call it inside the `DoWork()` of the `Backgroundworker` it won't block your main thread to call another `Backroundworkder.RunWorkerAsync()`

Comment: WaitOne() being called from my DoWork() method. I want it to stop what its doing until my UI has confirmed it has received a message then continue. I want to know if it is possible to determine if the WaitOne() method has been called without a global variable flag..